ImageFile created is being returned as 0 byte file, also not found if saved to storage
I'm trying to make an app that takes a picture and uploads it to a server, it is connected to the server already but the images generated by the code are always 0 bytes, I tried saving it to internal storage first and then uploading it but it still ends as a 0 byte file and it is not even found in the system. I would appreciate any help.
interface CameraResultHandler {
    fun handleCameraResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
}

class CameraHandler(private val activity: Activity): CameraResultHandler {
    lateinit var imageFile: File
    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    }
    fun startCamera(){
        dispatchTakePicture()
        handleCameraResult(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE, RESULT_OK, null)
    }    
    fun dispatchTakePicture() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            val photoFile: File? = runBlocking {
                try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    null
                }
            }
            photoFile?.also {
                imageFile = it
                takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager)?.also {
                    activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun handleCameraResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity).apply {
                setMessage("Uploading...")
                setCancelable(false)
                show()
            }
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                delay(5000) //ADDED A TIMER SO THAT UPLOAD IMAGE HAD TIME TO RUN, DIDN'T HELP
                uploadImage(imageFile) //UPLOADS THE FILE
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val imageFileName = "JPEG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_"
        val storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        )
        // Log the file path
        Log.d("CameraHandler", "File path: ${imageFile.absolutePath}")
        // Log the file size
        Log.d("CameraHandler", "File size: ${imageFile.length()} bytes")
        return imageFile
    }
}


createImageFile() Here you already create a file of zero bytes. Dont do that. The file schould completely be created by the Camera app. So dont create that file but assign the same value to photoFile.

Further you cannot just telll the Camera app that photoFile but should use a FileProvider.

as user blackapps mentioned, I didn't need to make a new function and just took the Uri/Bitmap generated by the camera itself to process the file and upload it. Thanks blackapps, I wish you only green lights on your next commute.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
